# C# FTP.ListDirectoryDetails - different response on different machines

Tags: c#, ftp, response

Below I copied part of my code where I connect to ftp and checks it content at given path.
The thing is, so far my app was running with no major issues. But today I was asked to install it on another one computer and then it came out its ftp methods do not work.

Till today app was running on 4-5 machines (win xp / win7), and Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails returned values HTMLlike: 
                `<DIR> ..
09/28/11 10:43 [GMT] <DIR> .`

(unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't ignore html tags inside code block...)

And on next machine My responses are like:
    `drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Oct 19 11:34 hr`

Does anyone have idea why it happens? How to solve that issue?

Below is part of my code that does the stuff

```
            FtpWebRequest request = FtpWebRequest.Create(path) as FtpWebRequest;
            LogAnything("ConnectTo(" + sPath + ")");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, pswd);
            request.UsePassive = true;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.KeepAlive = true;             

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            FtpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as FtpWebResponse;
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            string sPattern = @">(.*)<.A>";
            string sSource;
            ArrayList ContentList = new ArrayList();

            while ((sSource = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                LogAnything("Spam: " + sSource); 
            }
```

Best regards,
  Piotr

Answer (score 2):

FTP specification doesn't define a uniform format for file listing. The first format you see is Windows format, second is Unix format. The only way to get uniform listing is to use MLST and MLSD commands, but you would need some third-party component to work with listings and extended commands properly.

Comment: Is there any more possible formats for the listing? <br><br>If there is only two it will not be very complicated to check its format and parse response according to its type :)

Comment: @piotroslav Yes, the parser in Indy VCL library contains parsers for about 400 formats.

Answer (score -3):

FTP is the most unstable protocol I ever met. Many things can happen. Stream can be truncated without reason. Connection can be closed without explanation. Some response can change format when they want. Etc. All FTP code must be very careful because FTP in a very aggressive world for application.

Comment: What about it is unstable specifically?